# Height property is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, height

There is a worksheet in my web application. It has used a javascript function to add an empty line to the bottom of that work sheet. That javascript function looks like below.

```
ui.app.spreadsheet.FooterDataPadding.prototype.adjustPaddingToFooter = function () {
    this.getDomElement().style.height = this.getApplicationControl().getFooter().getDomElement().offsetHeight;
}
```

After running the function the html part looks like below.

```
div class="ui_app_spreadsheet_FooterPadding-layout " id="util_Document-uid185" style="height: 21px;"
```

In firefox and IE this works really fine. It adds that `21px` high empty line to the bottom of the worksheet. But in Chrome, even though it includes in the source, it doesn't show in the UI. I tried hard to find the solution for this. But couldn't. It would be a great help if anyone can find a solution for this.

Comment: Can you make a http://sscce.org/? As it stands, this is not reproducible

Comment: Where is your layout markup? How are we supposed to find out why it's not affected when any info about it is missing

Comment: @Bergi : what is a sscce.org?

Comment: Try to set also `min-height` for the element.

Comment: @AmilaFonseka: a [Short, Self Contained, Clean, Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Teemu: I added that. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty Div's sometime show abrupt behaviour in different browsers.

Try to set the innerHTML of the browser to empty or whitespace:

```
document.getElementById('your_elem').innerHTML = '&nbsp';
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be try following:

```
var domElement = this.getDomElement();
domElement.style.height = this.getApplicationControl().getFooter().getDomElement().offsetHeight;
domElement.innerHtml = "&nbsp;"
```

Or may be concate + "px" in your height statement.

Or

```
domElement.innerHTML="<div style='height:" + height + "px;'></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But SHANK's answer worked perfectly.Thanks anyway!! :)